# Can't find javascript project in eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, plugins

I already have Eclipse IDE for JAVA Developers, and have different projects created for Cucumber/JAVA. I want to create a project for Javascript now, but I am not getting the option in New Project, I tried installing Plugins too but it did not worked for me.

Can someone please help. I am new to Javascript.

Is it possible to do so without having to install another eclipse? I have my projects in the previous one which i don't want to loose. I tried installing previous version of eclipse for Eclipse Javascript but I am not able to do so and the only one i see is Eclipse IDE again.

Comment: which eclipse package are you using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers @shamnadsherief

Comment: @Lynx242 what to select here for Javascript? is this another eclipse download?

Comment: @Lynx242 what should i add here? nd how? I think this will help

Comment: Install [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) and make sure to open JavaScript files with the _Generic Text Editor_. There is no need and option to create a JavaScript project when using Wild Web Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0 , and then work with your JavaScript files using the Generic Text Editor. No project wizard or type is required.

Answer (score 0):

First go to help>marketplace and search for javascript plugin and install it.

[image]

[image]

After installation you can find an option here,

[image]